# Base class selection of a project in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

When I am developing a project in asp.net what should i keep in mind to select the classes so that I. can design my database. My project is on online bus ticket reservation.

Comment: Please clarify "select the classes so that I can design by database" - are you asking about choosing an ORM? Designing entity classes for your database? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about using Entity Framework Code-First, which allows you to build your domain object classes and then have the database generated from those classes.

[Code-First to a New Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj193542)